# Incorrectly processing RestTemplate response into object

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

I'm having some difficulty in parsing a response from a RestTemplate into an instance of a class I've defined.

When I come to process the results, it *does* give me the correct number of items in the array, but they are all set to default values - it seems unable to process the actual contents from each entry in the response.

This is my class:

```
public class Authority {

    private long localAuthorityId;
    private String localAuthorityIdCode;
    private String name;
    private String friendlyName;
    private String url;
    private String schemeUrl;
    private String email;
    private String regionName;
    private String fileName;
    private String fileNameWelsh;
    private int establishmentCount;
    private String creationDate;
    private String lastPublishedDate;
    private int schemeType;
    private Link[] links;

    public Authority() {}

    public Authority (long localAuthorityId, String localAuthorityIdCode, String name, String friendlyName, String url, String schemeUrl,
            String email, String regionName, String fileName, String fileNameWelsh, int establishmentCount, String creationDate,
            String lastPublishedDate, int schemeType, Link[] links) {
        this.localAuthorityId = localAuthorityId;
        this.localAuthorityIdCode = localAuthorityIdCode;
        this.name = name;
        this.friendlyName = friendlyName;
        this.url = url;
        this.schemeUrl = schemeUrl;
        this.email = email;
        this.regionName = regionName;
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.fileNameWelsh = fileNameWelsh;
        this.establishmentCount = establishmentCount;
        this.creationDate = creationDate;
        this.lastPublishedDate = lastPublishedDate;
        this.schemeType = schemeType;
        this.links = links;
    }

    public long getLocalAuthorityId() {
        return this.localAuthorityId;
    }

    public String getLocalAuthorityIdCode() {
        return this.localAuthorityIdCode;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public String getFriendlyName() {
        return this.friendlyName;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return this.url;
    }

    public String getSchemeUrl() {
        return this.schemeUrl;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return this.email;
    }

    public String getRegionName() {
        return this.regionName;
    }

    public String getFilename() {
        return this.fileName;
    }

    public String getFileNameWelsh() {
        return this.fileNameWelsh;
    }

    public int getEstablishmentCount() {
        return this.establishmentCount;
    }

    public String getCreationDate() {
        return this.creationDate;
    }

    public String getLastPublishedDate() {
        return this.lastPublishedDate;
    }

    public int getSchemeType() {
        return this.schemeType;
    }

    public Link[] getLinks() {
        return this.links;
    }
}
```

This is my response wrapper (where I've confirmed it only ever calls the empty constructor):

```
public class MyResponseWrapper {
    private Authority[] authorities;

    public MyResponseWrapper() {
        // this is always being called
    }

    public MyResponseWrapper(Authority[] authorities) {
        this.authorities = authorities;
    }

    public Authority[] getAuthorities() {
        return this.authorities;
    }
}
```

And this is how I'm using the RestTemplate:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.set("Accept", "application/json");
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>("parameters", headers);
ResponseEntity<MyResponseWrapper> res = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, MyResponseWrapper.class);
```

Here is the JSON I am attempting to parse (I only need the id and name parameters to be stored in MyClass):

```
{  
   "authorities":[  
      {  
         "LocalAuthorityId":197,
         "LocalAuthorityIdCode":"760",
         "Name":"Aberdeen City",
         "FriendlyName":"aberdeen-city",
         "Url":"http://www.aberdeencity.gov.uk",
         "SchemeUrl":"",
         "Email":"commercial@aberdeencity.gov.uk",
         "RegionName":"Scotland",
         "FileName":"http://ratings.food.gov.uk/OpenDataFiles/FHRS760en-GB.xml",
         "FileNameWelsh":null,
         "EstablishmentCount":1847,
         "CreationDate":"2010-08-17T15:30:24.87",
         "LastPublishedDate":"2018-02-08T00:35:50.717",
         "SchemeType":2,
         "links":[  
            {  
               "rel":"self",
               "href":"http://api.ratings.food.gov.uk/authorities/197"
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "LocalAuthorityId":198,
         "LocalAuthorityIdCode":"761",
         "Name":"Aberdeenshire",
         "FriendlyName":"aberdeenshire",
         "Url":"http://www.aberdeenshire.gov.uk/",
         "SchemeUrl":"",
         "Email":"environmental@aberdeenshire.gov.uk",
         "RegionName":"Scotland",
         "FileName":"http://ratings.food.gov.uk/OpenDataFiles/FHRS761en-GB.xml",
         "FileNameWelsh":null,
         "EstablishmentCount":2102,
         "CreationDate":"2010-08-17T15:30:24.87",
         "LastPublishedDate":"2018-02-24T00:34:15.547",
         "SchemeType":2,
         "links":[  
            {  
               "rel":"self",
               "href":"http://api.ratings.food.gov.uk/authorities/198"
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "LocalAuthorityId":277,
         "LocalAuthorityIdCode":"323",
         "Name":"Adur",
         "FriendlyName":"adur",
         "Url":"http://www.adur-worthing.gov.uk",
         "SchemeUrl":"",
         "Email":"publichealth.regulation@adur-worthing.gov.uk",
         "RegionName":"South East",
         "FileName":"http://ratings.food.gov.uk/OpenDataFiles/FHRS323en-GB.xml",
         "FileNameWelsh":null,
         "EstablishmentCount":417,
         "CreationDate":"2010-08-17T15:30:24.87",
         "LastPublishedDate":"2018-02-28T00:36:33.987",
         "SchemeType":1,
         "links":[  
            {  
               "rel":"self",
               "href":"http://api.ratings.food.gov.uk/authorities/277"
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "LocalAuthorityId":158,
         "LocalAuthorityIdCode":"055",
         "Name":"Allerdale",
         "FriendlyName":"allerdale",
         "Url":"http://www.allerdale.gov.uk",
         "SchemeUrl":"",
         "Email":"environmental.health@allerdale.gov.uk",
         "RegionName":"North West",
         "FileName":"http://ratings.food.gov.uk/OpenDataFiles/FHRS055en-GB.xml",
         "FileNameWelsh":null,
         "EstablishmentCount":1092,
         "CreationDate":"2010-08-17T15:30:24.87",
         "LastPublishedDate":"2018-02-28T00:33:58.31",
         "SchemeType":1,
         "links":[  
            {  
               "rel":"self",
               "href":"http://api.ratings.food.gov.uk/authorities/158"
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "LocalAuthorityId":48,
         "LocalAuthorityIdCode":"062",
         "Name":"Amber Valley",
         "FriendlyName":"amber-valley",
         "Url":"http://www.ambervalley.gov.uk",
         "SchemeUrl":"",
         "Email":"envhealth@ambervalley.gov.uk",
         "RegionName":"East Midlands",
         "FileName":"http://ratings.food.gov.uk/OpenDataFiles/FHRS062en-GB.xml",
         "FileNameWelsh":null,
         "EstablishmentCount":972,
         "CreationDate":"2010-08-17T15:30:24.87",
         "LastPublishedDate":"2018-02-28T00:34:14.493",
         "SchemeType":1,
         "links":[  
            {  
               "rel":"self",
               "href":"http://api.ratings.food.gov.uk/authorities/48"
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "LocalAuthorityId":334,
         "LocalAuthorityIdCode":"551",
         "Name":"Anglesey",
         "FriendlyName":"anglesey",
         "Url":"http://www.ynysmon.gov.uk",
         "SchemeUrl":"",
         "Email":"iechydyramgylchedd@ynysmon.gov.uk",
         "RegionName":"Wales",
         "FileName":"http://ratings.food.gov.uk/OpenDataFiles/FHRS551en-GB.xml",
         "FileNameWelsh":"http://ratings.food.gov.uk/OpenDataFiles/FHRS551cy-GB.xml",
         "EstablishmentCount":703,
         "CreationDate":"2010-08-17T15:30:24.87",
         "LastPublishedDate":"2018-02-28T00:34:28.853",
         "SchemeType":1,
         "links":[  
            {  
               "rel":"self",
               "href":"http://api.ratings.food.gov.uk/authorities/334"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "meta":{  
      "dataSource":"API",
      "extractDate":"2018-02-28T00:58:26.2673908+00:00",
      "itemCount":6,
      "returncode":"OK",
      "totalCount":6,
      "totalPages":1,
      "pageSize":6,
      "pageNumber":1
   },
   "links":[  
      {  
         "rel":"self",
         "href":"http://api.ratings.food.gov.uk/authorities"
      },
      {  
         "rel":"first",
         "href":"http://api.ratings.food.gov.uk/authorities/1/6"
      },
      {  
         "rel":"previous",
         "href":"http://api.ratings.food.gov.uk/authorities/1/6"
      },
      {  
         "rel":"next",
         "href":"http://api.ratings.food.gov.uk/authorities/1/6"
      },
      {  
         "rel":"last",
         "href":"http://api.ratings.food.gov.uk/authorities/1/6"
      }
   ]
}
```

I know I'm making a really basic mistake in attempting to parse this response. Would really appreciate if someone could point it out. Cheers.

Comment: do you have a sample json which you are trying to map to this Wrapper class?

Comment: Sorry, yes, will edit the question to include

Comment: Where have you defined the mapping between the JSON key names and the Java fields? I am guessing you want to map "LocalAuthorityId" to class field "id" - where do you define this mapping?

Comment: Short answer - I've not defined those mappings. How do I do that?

Comment: restTemplate.exchange would automatically map the json fields if you have attributes with the same name in your class.

Comment: In the non-sanitised code, they are named the same.

Comment: if the class field names are the same as json field names, you don't need to define those as Jackson will do it for you. If there are differences you have to specify the mapping via @ JsonProperty annotation and you can use @ JsonIgnoreProperties on the class you want to deserialize the JSON into.

Comment: But the names are mapped correctly in the non-sanitised code. Let me edit the question to show it properly.

Comment: `LocalAuthorityId` is not the same as `localAuthorityId` (first character different).

Comment: @manish Changing the first character to upper case completely destroys the attempted mapping - the Links[] part actually works, but becomes null when you capitalise the first letter

Comment: @HomerPlata, I merely pointed out the mismatch between the Java and JSON field names, which is causing the deserialization to fail. You should either change the JSON field names or add `@JsonProperty` annotation to each Java field whose name is not the same as that of the corresponding JSON field.

Comment: @manish Ah! I see now, thanks for your help. I had to map the lower case version to the upper case version. Between you and hovanessyan I've got my answer (and thanks everyone else too). If one of you guys want to put that in a formal answer, I'll accept it.